# QEMU Process Allocates all of Memory to the Windows VM

Tags: windows, qemu

Whenever I emulate a linux-based OS using `qemu`, I see the amount of memory that has been allocated to the VM via `htop` command is equal to the amount of memory that processes within the guest OS really need.
But If I emulate a windows-based OS with the same `qemu` options given for linux-based scenario, I saw from the host point of view that all of the specified memory is allocated to the `qemu` process. ( for example, 8GB memory will be allocated if the `qemu` process launch with 8GB memory ). However, from the VM point of view, the amount of using memory observed from `task manager` is much lower. (for example 2GB)
I thought that maybe the ballooning driver should not be installed properly. But I could manage memory allocation by issuing `qmp` ballooning query.
How can I have dynamic memory allocation enabled for windows guest OS as well as for linux-based family?
Below is the `qemu` command I'm issuing for both linux-base and windows-base OSes.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm -machine q35 -smp 1 -m 8192M -name test-ballooning -uuid ID
-cpu host,host-cache-info=on,l3-cache=off
-device qemu-xhci,id=xhci
-device usb-tablet,bus=xhci.0
-daemonize -vnc IP:0,to=100,password=off,websocket=on
-chardev socket,id=qmp,path=PATH.qmp,server=on,wait=off -mon chardev=qmp,mode=control,pretty=off
-chardev socket,id=hmp,path=PATH.hmp,server=on,wait=off -mon chardev=hmp,mode=readline
-chardev socket,path=PATH.qga,server=on,wait=off,id=qga0
-device virtio-serial -device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0
-no-shutdown
-drive file=IMAGE.img,if=none,id=disk0,l2-cache-size=8M,format=qcow2
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=disk0,scsi=off,bootindex=2
-drive if=none,id=cdrom0,file=CDROM.iso,format=raw
-device virtio-scsi -device scsi-cd,drive=cdrom0,bootindex=1
-nodefaults -vga cirrus -device AC97
-chardev socket,id=serialport,path=PATH.tty,server=on,wait=off
-serial chardev:serialport
-netdev tap,id=nic0,ifname=IFNAME,script=no,downscript=no -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=nic0,mac=MAC
-device virtio-balloon-pci,deflate-on-oom=on
```

My host operating system is `Debian 11` and the version of `qemu` I'm using is `QEMU emulator version 5.2.0 (Debian 1:5.2+dfsg-11+deb11u2)`